java Android connectGatt return true without any mGattCallback
I have android BLE application for connecting to NRF52833 BLE GATT server.
Everything works fine except first connection after android device restart.
Device.connectGatt returns true, but there is no mGattCallback event.
If I do adapter.startLeScan (for 300ms) and adapter.stopLeScan, next connection to GATT server works, also with correct mGattCallback;
Now I have writed "try connect, delay 2s,if wasn't GattCallback->startLeScan+stopLeScan and connectGatt" procedure, but I want to know correct solution for this problem.

Please provide the minimal code needed to reproduce the issue. Do you connect to a non-bonded device using a random static address without first scanning after it?
